# should I give "s" to the verb "get" in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar

should I give "s" to the verb "get" in the sentence below?

> "if one makes sure that they are rich and then **get** married, they will be happy"

Comment: Hi, to improve this question, what is your opinion and why?  “Makes and then gets” or “makes and then get”?

Comment: @whiskeychief, It's tricky, but I'd go with: *they are rich and then they get married*.

Comment: The problem re ***get/gets*** only arises because of preceding clumsy juxtaposition of explicitly singular ***one*** and *semantically* singular ***they*** (which still functions *syntactically* as a plural). If the first two pronouns are consistent, the third one doesn't cause problems. Either *If **they make** sure that **they are** rich and then [**they**] **get** married, **they** will be happy* OR *If **one makes** sure that **one is** rich and then [**one**] **gets** married, **one** will be happy*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stylistic (and possibly semantic) problem with the sentence because it mixes two different pronouns, one of which takes a singular form and the other which takes a plural form.

Any of the following would be quite fine:

> If **one** ***makes*** sure that **one** ***is*** rich and then ***gets*** married, **one** will be happy.
>
> If **they** ***make*** sure that **they** ***are*** rich and then ***get*** married, **they** will be happy.
>
> If **you** ***make*** sure that **you** ***are*** rich and then ***get*** married, **you** will be happy.

But in the original version, when you use *one* in the first part of the sentence followed by *they* in the second part, the shift from the singular to the plural sounds strange.

---

The use of *they are*, with the pronoun and verb being immediately next to each other, isn't a problem. But by the time *get married* is reached, it's far enough removed from both *one* and *they* that, in terms of parsing the sentence, the referent (and plurality) becomes ambiguous.

Another problem is the simple fact that *rich and **then get(s)** married* is an unusual phrasing in its own right. Even if one of the first three variations above is used, it would still sound a little bit strange.

There is also a another potential problem with using one of first three variations. It's possible that the pronouns *one* and *they* are actually referring to different people.

For instance:

> If <sup>[one]</sup>**Shelly** makes sure that <sup>[they]</sup> **her friends** are rich and then get married, <sup>[they]</sup> **her friends** will be happy.

In this interpretation, *one* refers to one person, but *they* refers to *different* people. If you change all of the pronouns to the *same* pronoun, then the distinction would be lost and the meaning would change.

---

For all of these reasons, I suggest simply removing *then get(s)* from the sentence altogether:

> If one makes sure that they are rich and <s>then get</s> married, they will be happy.
>
> → ✔ If one makes sure that they are rich and married, they will be happy.

There is still some ambiguity over *one* and *they*, and who the pronouns refer to, but the sentence works no matter how it's interpreted.